# Reading JSON elements from a field value using REACT

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm using REACT to read the value from an input field containing a JSON object.

I'm able to get the JSON string value into a const containing the following:

```
{"name": "This is the name element"}
```

But when I try to extract the value of the "name" element from the JSON, I get an "undefined" response.

When I get the same JSON text from a js file like this:

```
export default
    {"name": "This is the name field"}
```

and import it using:

```
import JSONObject from './JSONObjectFile'
```

Then it works fine.

What do I need to do to achieve the same thing when retrieving the JSON object from the text field on the HTML page?

Here's the whole code:

```
import './App.css';
import JSONObject from './aa_DDFFormConfigJSON'

function App() {
  var myJSON;

  function ConfigJSONReady(event) {
    myJSON = document.getElementsByName("myJSONField")[0].value;
    //This returns "undefined" instead of the actual "name" element value 
    console.log("myJSON.name using input field: " + myJSON.name); 

    // This is the same JSON object from a file, but it works fine
    myJSON = JSONObject;
    console.log("myJSON.name using file import: " + myJSON.name); 
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        Everything here is in a REACT App
        <p>Success!!</p>
      </header>

      <form>
        <textarea rows="10"
          cols="200"
          maxlength="5000"
          id='myJSONField'
          defaultValue='{"name": "This is the name field"}'>
        </textarea>
        <input
          name="DDFConfigJSONReady"
          id="DDFConfigJSONReady"
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={ConfigJSONReady}
        />

      </form>
    </div>
  );


}

export default App;
```

Comment: The value returned from your input is not in JSON format. You can confirm by logging in the console `typeof yourvariable`. Wrap `myJSON` with the function `JSON.parse(myJSON)` to convert it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Values read from input fields are of `string` type, which means, your JSON object is a `string` as well. In order to convert your JSON string to a JSON object, you need to use `JSON.parse()` method.

```
const myObj = "{"key": "value"}";
const parsedObj = JSON.parse(myObj);
```

And, if you want to convert your JSON object to a `string`, you can use `JSON.stringify()` in the similar manner.

```
const stringifiedObj = JSON.stringify(parsedObj);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong API to get the `textarea` value, you didn't give the `name` attribute value to the element.

```
<textarea rows="10"
  cols="200" // you are missing `name="myJSONField"` 
  maxlength="5000"
  id='myJSONField'
  defaultValue='{"name": "This is the name field"}'>
</textarea>
```

Instead, you can use `document.getElementById()` as you already have give an `id` to the element.

And the `value` you got from the element is a text, you should parse it to `JSON` using `JSON.parse()`.

So the code will look like this:

```
myJSON = document.getElementById("myJSONField").value;
//This returns "undefined" instead of the actual "name" element value
console.log("`myJSON.name` using input field: " + JSON.parse(myJSON).name);

// This is the same JSON object from a file, but it works fine
myJSON = JSONObject;
console.log("myJSON.name using file import: " + myJSON.name);
```

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-raman-ktvdzi?file=/src/App.js:141-513

Comment: thankyou. And yes, the element reference was ByName due to my type when writing the sample app. It was't in my full app.